# Offer access to a private page without login

Tags: php

So I've been struggling with a nice and easy way to allow users to access a private page without asking them to fill out a login/password form.

What I'm thinking about using right now is for each private page I generate a uniqueid (using php uniqid function) and then send the URI to the user. He would access his private page as "www.mywebsite.com/private_page/13ffa2c4a". I think it's relatively safe and user friendly, without asking too much of information. I thought maybe when the user access this page it would ask for it's e-mail just to be sure, but the best would be nothing at all.

Is this really safe? I mean not internet banking safe, but enough for a simple access? Do you think there's a better solution? Thanks. :)

Comment: "security by obscurity" is _never_ a good idea (because its _never_ any kind of secure). Its extremely easy to find valid pages by just brute-forcing.

Comment: But then again I could just send a code to the user and tell him to enter that code on my website. Wouldn't it be the same thing? That's what some websites do nowadays, isn't it? I mean, isn't there a way to avoid brute-forcing the same way we do with passwords?

Comment: I think if you want these pages to truly be private then you will need to ask for some kind of authentication. As KingCrunch said, this is just "security" by obscurity which doesn't really work. Also, if you were thinking of asking the user for a code or for their email address, then why not just use a login form? That is assuming that the users who will receive these URLs are registered on your site.

Comment: They aren't. The idea behind simplifying the access method is because most of the users would be technologically impaired people, so the less ask them, the more they will be pleased. Also, I'd have to create a new login/password every now and then because they will probably forget about them.

Comment: Anyway, since the question has been downvoted twice, I'm guessing it's a irrelevant discussion and I should stick with basic login/password scheme.

Comment: I don't think your idea is conceptually terrible (that is, improving the login process for technologically-impaired users), but this is probably not the way to ask that question.

Comment: I guess you're right. I just didn't know exactly how to ask, so I went  with what I was trying to do to see if it was such a bad idea. It turned out to be, so I'll keep looking for another solution...

Comment: It's perfectly okay for you to ask a conceptual question like that, provided that you include enough information so that other people understand that you're looking for a specific solution and not just making a Seinfeld-esque witty observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your site is data driven, you could make a unique key like you're saying and pass that to your user. When the user comes back they would hit a data bound template page which will go and look for that key, if they key is found, then reutrn the elements of the page to them. Once that key is used, you could then deactive it or delete it out of the system so that the template page wouldn't be able to re-render the same data twice because it couldn't find that key anymore. You might also want to make sure that you're not caching that page or putting anything into session (keep as little public as possible).

This is not a great solution, but might be able to work with out forcing someone to login to something.

Good luck, and hope this helps some.

Answer (score 1):

This is not secure at all. If you make a password field, you will still be able to bruteforce it (if you don't implement delays during the authentication process), but at least its value will not be stored in the browser history.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I forgot about that side effect (browser history).